# Run Gitlab CI job on merge to master for only changes

Tags: gitlab-ci

Is there a way to reliably execute a job on merge to master only when there are changes to the script? I'm using

```
vm-build:
  image: 
    name: path_to_image
  stage: vm-deploy
  only:
    changes:
      - job.gitlab-ci.yml
    refs:
      - master
  except:
    - schedules
    - triggers
  script:
    - ansible-playbook playbooks/pb_job.yml
  tags:
    - docker
```

but it seems to execute 'job' on different commits to master where job.gitlab-ci.yml hasn't changed. I haven't found a rhyme or reason to why though.

Comment: At least I would need to see the complete definition and not just this small portion.

Comment: The above job will continue to fire after other jobs are committed to master and this job file hasn't changed. Trying to figure out why it still shows 'job' file as changed when it hasn't (sometimes).

Comment: Also, every time we create a new merge request, it executes the jobs.

Answer (score 3):

The following `.gitlab-ci.yml` runs only on changes to the file `jobs.gitlab-ci.yml` on the `master` branch:

```
myjob:
  script:
    - echo I am a CI job
  only:
      changes:
        - job.gitlab-ci.yml
      refs:
        - master
```

It does not run on changes to any other file in the `master` branch.